# Sort command changes string output

Tags: bash, sort, command-history, uniq

I stumbled on this anomaly regarding the sort command and I can't find an explamation to why it happens -

running the following command:

```
cat ~/.bash_history | uniq -c | sort -h -r | head
```

Should output the top most used 10 command sequences I ran in the system, but in reality it fails to do so, the output shows as if I ran all commands once.

but upon running:

```
cat ~/.bash_history | sort | uniq -c | sort -h -r | head
```

It seems to work, and I can't understand why, can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 3):

`uniq` only filters *adjacent* lines. Say you have a file like this:

```
$ cat foobar.txt
foo
bar
foo
```

with two non-adjacent `foo` lines. Then `uniq -c` counts each of them once, while sorting the file first means `uniq -c` sees them as adjacent and counts them as one line that appears twice:

```
$ uniq -c foobar.txt
  1 foo
  1 bar
  1 foo
$ sort foobar.txt | uniq -c
  1 bar
  2 foo
```

Comment: Ah! this explains it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

`uniq` is a POSIX utility. You used `uniq -c` and it works like this:

> The `uniq` utility shall read an input file comparing **adjacent** lines, and write one copy of each input line on the output. The second and succeeding copies of repeated **adjacent** input lines shall not be written. The trailing  of each line in the input shall be ignored when doing comparisons.
>
> **Repeated lines in the input shall not be detected if they are not adjacent.**
>
> […]
>
> `-c`
> Precede each output line with a count of the number of times the line occurred in the input.

([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html), emphasis mine)

This means that non-adjacent lines are treated as if they were different. In your use case you need to `sort` first to make identical lines adjacent. Only then `uniq` will do what you want.